# Unable to set 100% height on bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my css:

```
html{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.footer p{
  line-height: 60px;
}

.messages {
  /*background-color: blue;*/
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

This is my markup (using blaze for template rendering):

```
<template name="messages">
  <div class="container messages">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 conversations">
        {{> message}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 conversation-holder">
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
        <div class="conversation">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is my output:

[image]

What I want is that the line between the list of conversations and the title(John Doe( on the right) should be of 100% height and that any overflow should be scrollable.

I have set the `min-height` and `height` of the `.messages` container to be 100% with the `!important` but it does not work i do not know why.

How do I make it 100%? Thanks.

P.S: Here is the template after rendering:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="__blaze-root">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <!-- navbar stuff removed for better understanding-->
    </nav>
    <div class="container messages">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 conversations">
          <a href="#">
          <div class="message">
            <div class="conversation-title">
              <img class="pull-left img-circle" height="50px" src="/images/dummy-profile-pic.png" width="auto">
              <p class="pull-left">John Doe</p>
            </div>
          </div></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 conversation-holder">
          <h1>John Doe</h1>
          <div class="conversation"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only elements which are ``absolute``  to their parent can be given a height of ``100%``.I only see the footer being positioned ``absolute``.

Comment: @JoshCrowe So i should first apply absolute positioning to the container then to the row then to the conversations-holder?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that you are using bootstrap framework. You have to cascade the height from the parent div to the inner div till it reaches the `.message` element.

Otherwise, you can't set the height as 100%. (Any padding or margin in the intermediate div would introduce vertical scroll)

Fiddle that shows the 100% to 2 level down from the body tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/zrbgw/

Solution 2: You have to use `position:absolute` for `.message`

Solution 3: You can use `position:fixed`

But solution 2 & 3 will remove the elements out of the content flow resulting in need of setting a proper parent height.

Comment: So you are saying that I should first apply absolute positioning to the container then to the row then to the conversations-holder?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui  the absolute div will act based on a relative div around it... Even body tag can have relative.. But when the .message div is nested to this level it is risk that you can't expect everyone in the team would know about. Body & message relation

Comment: You can set the conversations as absolute and use Javascript to set .message height

Comment: Isn't there any other approach?